# SQL find sum of entries by date including previous date

Tags: sql, h2

This might not be possible, but here this is the request I'm trying to translate into SQL:
For every date where at least one entry exists in the `ACCOUNT_ENTRY` table, I want to find the sum of all entries for all accounts (in the `ACCOUNT` table) for that date. If an account doesn't have an entry for that particular date, I want to use the next latest entry up to that point.

Note that I'm currently doing this on an H2 DB, but that could change in the future so I'm trying to stay away from vendor specific Stored Procedures.

#### Example

##### `ACCOUNT` table

| ID | ACCOUNT_LABEL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | account 123 |
| 2 | account 456 |
| 3 | account 789 |

##### `ACCOUNT_ENTRY` table

| ID | ACCOUNT_ID | ENTRY_DATE | BOOK_VALUE | MARKET_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 1 | 2021-05-31 | 100 | 110 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-05-28 | 90 | 100 |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-05-28 | 70 | 80 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-05-28 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-05-27 | 80 | 90 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-27 | 60 | 70 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-05-27 | 40 | 50 |

#### Desired result

| ENTRY_DATE | SUM_OF_BOOK_VAL | SUM_OF_MARKET_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 | 180 | 210 |
| 2021-05-28 | 210 | 240 |
| 2021-05-31 | 220 | 250 |

- `2021-05-27` Book value = 80 + 60 + 40 (Row ID 1 + 2 + 3)
- `2021-05-27` Market value = 90 + 70 + 50 (Row ID 1 + 2 + 3)
- `2021-05-28` Book value = 90 + 70 + 50 (Row ID 4 + 5 + 6)
- `2021-05-28` Market value = 100 + 80 + 60 (Row ID 4 + 5 + 6)
- **`2021-05-31` is equal to the results from `2021-05-28` + the new single new entry from `2021-05-31` (Row ID = 7)**

  - Book Value = 70 + 50 + 100 = 220
  - Market Value = 80 + 60 + 110 = 250

#### Result I can get so far

| ENTRY_DATE | SUM_OF_BOOK_VAL | SUM_OF_MARKET_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 | 180 | 210 |
| 2021-05-28 | 210 | 240 |
| 2021-05-31 | 100 | 110 |

This would be easy to do in my application code, but I was hoping to leave the compute to the DB and not transport all the data over to the application. I could also roll data forward, but then I could end up with significant chunks of data which aren't necessary.

Here's the query I'm using so far, but it doesn't handle situations where it has to look back at previous entries.

#### Query

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS ENTRYDATE,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN A.JOINT_ACCOUNT = 'TRUE' THEN MARKET_VALUE / 2
            ELSE MARKET_VALUE
        END
    ) AS MARKETVALUE,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN A.JOINT_ACCOUNT = 'TRUE' THEN BOOK_VALUE / 2
            ELSE BOOK_VALUE
        END
    ) AS BOOKVALUE
FROM
    ACCOUNT_ENTRY AE
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNT A ON AE.ACCOUNT_ID = A.ID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID,
            TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
            AE.ACCOUNT_ID AS AID
        FROM
            ACCOUNT_ENTRY AE
        GROUP BY
            AE.ACCOUNT_ID,
            TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    ) MAX_ENTRIES ON AE.ID = MAX_ENTRIES.MAX_ID
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY
    TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') DESC
```

This might not be possible, but here this is the request I'm trying to translate into SQL:
For every date where at least one entry exists in the `ACCOUNT_ENTRY` table, I want to find the sum of all entries for all accounts (in the `ACCOUNT` table) for that date. If an account doesn't have an entry for that particular date, I want to use the next latest entry up to that point.

Note that I'm currently doing this on an H2 DB, but that could change in the future so I'm trying to stay away from vendor specific Stored Procedures.

#### Example

##### `ACCOUNT` table

| ID | ACCOUNT_LABEL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | account 123 |
| 2 | account 456 |
| 3 | account 789 |

##### `ACCOUNT_ENTRY` table

| ID | ACCOUNT_ID | ENTRY_DATE | BOOK_VALUE | MARKET_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 1 | 2021-05-31 | 100 | 110 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-05-28 | 90 | 100 |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-05-28 | 70 | 80 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-05-28 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-05-27 | 80 | 90 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-27 | 60 | 70 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-05-27 | 40 | 50 |

#### Desired result

| ENTRY_DATE | SUM_OF_BOOK_VAL | SUM_OF_MARKET_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 | 180 | 210 |
| 2021-05-28 | 210 | 240 |
| 2021-05-31 | 220 | 250 |

- `2021-05-27` Book value = 80 + 60 + 40 (Row ID 1 + 2 + 3)
- `2021-05-27` Market value = 90 + 70 + 50 (Row ID 1 + 2 + 3)
- `2021-05-28` Book value = 90 + 70 + 50 (Row ID 4 + 5 + 6)
- `2021-05-28` Market value = 100 + 80 + 60 (Row ID 4 + 5 + 6)
- **`2021-05-31` is equal to the results from `2021-05-28` + the new single new entry from `2021-05-31` (Row ID = 7)**

  - Book Value = 70 + 50 + 100 = 220
  - Market Value = 80 + 60 + 110 = 250

#### Result I can get so far

| ENTRY_DATE | SUM_OF_BOOK_VAL | SUM_OF_MARKET_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 | 180 | 210 |
| 2021-05-28 | 210 | 240 |
| 2021-05-31 | 100 | 110 |

This would be easy to do in my application code, but I was hoping to leave the compute to the DB and not transport all the data over to the application. I could also roll data forward, but then I could end up with significant chunks of data which aren't necessary.

Here's the query I'm using so far, but it doesn't handle situations where it has to look back at previous entries.

#### Query

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS ENTRYDATE,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN A.JOINT_ACCOUNT = 'TRUE' THEN MARKET_VALUE / 2
            ELSE MARKET_VALUE
        END
    ) AS MARKETVALUE,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN A.JOINT_ACCOUNT = 'TRUE' THEN BOOK_VALUE / 2
            ELSE BOOK_VALUE
        END
    ) AS BOOKVALUE
FROM
    ACCOUNT_ENTRY AE
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNT A ON AE.ACCOUNT_ID = A.ID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID,
            TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
            AE.ACCOUNT_ID AS AID
        FROM
            ACCOUNT_ENTRY AE
        GROUP BY
            AE.ACCOUNT_ID,
            TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    ) MAX_ENTRIES ON AE.ID = MAX_ENTRIES.MAX_ID
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY
    TO_CHAR(ENTRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') DESC
```

### SOLUTION Found

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff for sharing the COALESCE and LAG functions.

First, just to simplify my query, I created a view. This isn't relevant to the challenge I was facing, but important so that I could eliminate multiple entries for the same account and same day

```sql
create view LATEST_ACCOUNT_ENTRY as
select
   max(id) as entry_id,
   account_id,
   to_char(entry_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as e_date
from
   account_entry
group by
   account_id,
   e_date
```

#### Final Query (going to be simplified)

```sql
select
   e_date,
   sum(coalesce(BOOK_VALUE, PREVIOUS_BOOK_VALUE)),
   sum(coalesce(MARKET_VALUE, PREVIOUS_MARKET_VALUE))
from
   (
      select
         dates.e_date,
         acc_id,
         entry_id,
         book_value,
         LAG(book_value) OVER (
            partition by dates.acc_id
            order by
               dates.e_date
         ) as previous_book_value,
         market_value,
         LAG(market_value) OVER (
            partition by dates.acc_id
            order by
               dates.e_date
         ) as previous_market_value
      from
         (
            select
               distinct to_char(entry_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as e_date,
               accts.id as acc_id
            from
               account_entry
               cross join (
                  select
                     id
                  from
                     account
               ) accts
         ) dates
         left join (
            select
               lae.ACCOUNT_ID,
               lae.E_DATE,
               lae.ENTRY_ID,
               CASE
                        WHEN JOINT_ACCOUNT = 'TRUE' THEN BOOK_VALUE / 2 
                        ELSE BOOK_VALUE
                    END as BOOK_VALUE,
                    CASE
                        WHEN JOINT_ACCOUNT = 'TRUE' THEN MARKET_VALUE / 2 
                        ELSE MARKET_VALUE
                    END as MARKET_VALUE
            from
               LATEST_ACCOUNT_ENTRY lae
               inner join account_entry ae on lae.ENTRY_ID = ae.id
               inner join account acc on ae.account_id = acc.id
         ) entries on dates.e_date = entries.e_date
         and dates.acc_id = entries.account_id
   )
group by
   e_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by generating rows for all dates and accounts and then using `lag(ignore nulls)` to get the most recent value.  So, for the rows:

```
select a.account_id, d.entry_date, ae.book_val, ae.market_val,
       coalesce(ae.book_val,
                lag(ae.book_val) ignore nulls over (partition by a.account_id order by d.entry_date)
               ) as imputed_book_val,
       coalesce(ae.market_val,
                lag(ae.market_val) ignore nulls over (partition by a.account_id order by d.entry_date)
               ) as imputed_market_val
from (select distinct account_id from account_entry) a cross join
     (select distinct entry_date from account_entry) d left join
     account_entry ae
     on ae.account_id = a.account_id and
        ae.entry_date = d.entry_date;
```

Then you can aggregate this:

```
select entry_date, sum(imputed_book_val), sum(imputed_market_val)
from (select a.account_id, d.entry_date, ae.book_val, ae.market_val,
             coalesce(ae.book_val,
                      lag(ae.book_val) ignore nulls over (partition by a.account_id order by d.entry_date)
                     ) as imputed_book_val,
             coalesce(ae.market_val,
                      lag(ae.market_val) ignore nulls over (partition by a.account_id order by d.entry_date)
                     ) as imputed_market_val
      from (select distinct account_id from account_entry) a cross join
           (select distinct entry_date from account_entry) d left join
           account_entry ae
           on ae.account_id = a.account_id and
              ae.entry_date = d.entry_date
     ) ad
group by entry_date;
```

Comment: This isn't exactly fixing my issue but it's bringing me a LOT closer. I had no idea about the LAG() and COALESCE() functions. Once I've sorted it out, I'll mark this answer as accepted and share what I had to change to make it work. Once such situation is that `entry_date` is has date and time and there could be multiple entries for the same day. So I'm working to get this sorted out. Thanks again!

Comment: @motopascyyy . . . I don't see why having a time component would be a problem.  The values would still be ordered correctly.  However, you might want to truncate the date for the `d` subquery.

Comment: Figured it out thanks to your help, and I've added my interim solution to the question for others to see.